# background of every page except homepage are blured

Tags: css, wordpress

I'm trying to make a website using wordpress, and I got a default background for every page.

The homepage background shouldn't be blur and all the rest of the pages should be, the problem is that I blur all the pages and cannot blur specific pages.

this is the code:

```
.container-centered
{
  position: fixed;
  left:0;
  top:0;
  height:100%;
  width:100%;
  background-image: url("http://localhost/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/fundo-home-1920px.jpg");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
  -webkit-filter: blur(13px);
  -moz-filter: blur(13px);
  -o-filter: blur(13px);
  -ms-filter: blur(13px);
  filter: blur(13px);
}
```

Comment: Add a specific class to homepage and exclude it from the blur effect.

Comment: With this selector, you will blur all .container-centered sections on every page. You can add additional properties for non-blurred section like this: #page-id .container-centered {...}. This should be after the main style for all other sections.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could add a class to the body tag on the homepage (front-page) and then with CSS only have it target the container when it doesn't have that class. For example...

***CSS***

```
.container-centered {
  position: fixed;
  left:0;
  top:0;
  height:100%;
  width:100%;
  background-image: url("http://localhost/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/fundo-home-1920px.jpg");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
  -webkit-filter: blur(13px);
  -moz-filter: blur(13px);
  -o-filter: blur(13px);
  -ms-filter: blur(13px);
  filter: blur(13px);
}

.container-centered.home-no_blur {
  -webkit-filter: blur(0px);
  -moz-filter: blur(0px);
  -o-filter: blur(0px);
  -ms-filter: blur(0px);
  filter: blur(0px);
}
```

***PHP***

*Add this to your header.php file where the body tag is.*

```
<?php if ( is_front_page() ) : ?>

    <body class="<?php body_class('home-no_blur'); ?>">

<?php else : ?>

    <body class="<?php body_class(); ?>">

<?php endif; ?>
```

That will then reset the blur effect to 0px (no blur) on the homepage. See this for more information on [setting a static page](https://codex.wordpress.org/Creating_a_Static_Front_Page).

If your *list of posts/articles (the blog) is the homepage/on the front-page*, then use [`is_home()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/is_home/) instead. But by the sounds of it you're using a static front-page, *from what I gathered*.

Comment: thanks a lot for the help!!!!, I did some changes using what u gave me and figure it out!

Comment: No worries glad I could help! The codex is great if you want to make it more technical.

Answer (score 1):

Have you got a specific class as an ancestor of your image on your homepage? if so you could do the following:

```
.container-centered
{
  position: fixed;
  left:0;
  top:0;
  height:100%;
  width:100%;
  background-image: url("http://localhost/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/fundo-home-1920px.jpg");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
  -webkit-filter: blur(13px);
  -moz-filter: blur(13px);
  -o-filter: blur(13px);
  -ms-filter: blur(13px);
  filter: blur(13px);
}

.homepage-class .container-centered
{
  position: fixed;
  left:0;
  top:0;
  height:100%;
  width:100%;
  background-image: url("http://localhost/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/fundo-home-1920px.jpg");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
  -webkit-filter: blur(0px);
  -moz-filter: blur(0px);
  -o-filter: blur(0px);
  -ms-filter: blur(0px);
  filter: blur(0px);
}
```

If not, I would suggest you do it. With WordPress you can set a new file called "front-page.php" in your template directory and edit it there. WordPress will automatically recognize this file as your home page if it is set to "static" in your WordPress admin page.

Source: [Click here](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/template-hierarchy/#front-page-display)

Comment: thanks for the help, you were very helpful and gave a quick response!!

Answer (score 0):

By default WordPress should give your home page the body class of home.

I would personally use the not filter like so:

```
.container-centered
{
  position: fixed;
  left:0;
  top:0;
  height:100%;
  width:100%;
  background-image: url("http://localhost/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/fundo-home-1920px.jpg");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
}
body:not(.home) .container-centered {
  -webkit-filter: blur(13px);
  -moz-filter: blur(13px);
  -o-filter: blur(13px);
  -ms-filter: blur(13px);
  filter: blur(13px);
}
```